# React props failing to compile as value of attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
Header.render
C:/CodingProjects/FirstReactProject/biochemicals/src/components/header/Header.js:28
  25 | <ul className="NavMenu">
  26 |   <HeaderDropDown
  27 |     name="Supplements"
> 28 |     firstChem={AlphaLipoicAcid.props.title}
```

I'm rendering header.js with these components imported:

```
import { HeaderDropDown } from "../header/HeaderItem";    
import { AlphaLipoicAcid } from "../chemicals/supplements/ALA";
```

This is the code nested in header.js render return (render tested before, it shows up in browser so I assume it succesfully goes through its process to get there):

```
 <HeaderDropDown
              name="Supplements"
              firstChem={AlphaLipoicAcid.props.title}
            />
```

& this nested in the return of render in HeaderItem.js:

```
<button onClick={this.props.eventHandler}>
              {this.props.firstChem}
            </button>
```

I'm trying to display the title prop of component AlphaLipoicAcid as inner HTML of button elements of HeaderDropDown component, which is returned in render of header.js, which is rendered to DOM, but am getting the error shown at top of question, thanks for the help!

Comment: please show us  "AlphaLipoicAcid"  component. what going on inside

Comment: `props` is an object that is sent to each React component by its parent component, so you can't access props of other component in your component, also here you are trying to say the component name directly `AlphaLipoicAcid` and access its props, this is not acceptable in any Object Oriented Programming you should be working with instances of the class not its name directly unless the function/property is declared `static`,

what are you trying to achieve? and it would be better if you paste your complete code file instead of these small snippets